# One of the usb port still has power

Tags: windows-8, usb-3, usb-modem

My laptop runs windows 8 and has 2 USB 3.0. port. One day, when I shut down my laptop, I forgot to take off my USB modem. But the USB modem light is still blinking.
I tried to move it to the other port, and the light is not blinking. I assume that the second port has no power. But why did the first one have power?

Comment: To prevent that usb port still have power after shutdown go to BIOS and set EuP / ErP on.

Answer (score 1):

This is so devices still operate after PC shutdown, this is considered a feature on some laptops, for example this can be used for charging a cell phone or other device after the laptop is shut down. Most laptops have a setting in the bios to disable "always on usb". USB Ports that have this feature are yellow.

[image]

Comment: But my USB port color is blue like the other USB 3.0 port

Comment: Then there is something wrong with that port, it should not do that.